# After hook for the entire feature in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

In cucucmber i want to run a step after all the scenarios in a feature are run, can I have an after hook for the entire feature, I currently have after hooks for each scenario.

Comment: As far as I'm aware (and based on [this Github wiki page](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks)) you can only have after hooks for a scenario, step, tag, or on a global scale, but not based on the feature.

Comment: Why do you want to run something after each Feature, but not after each scenario?  Are you setting up data that you're using for all the tests and you want to tear it down at the end of the feature run?

Answer (score 3):

I know its been a long time, but i havent been a user here for long but,
There is an exit hook that is used like this:

```
at_exit do
  # Add code here
end
```

This should be placed in your env.rb file or the features/support directory

Here's [a great link](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks)

Comment: `at_exit` code is invoked after for all features, not after one feature

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom formatter, and use the after_feature method.

(I used to have a link with more information, but @katta just pointed out that its no longer available)

Comment: your link is password protected

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a workaround, but you could just have scenarios at the beginning and the end of the feature for setup/teardown. Scenarios are run in the order that they are specified so as long as you have the setup scenario at the top and the teardown at the bottom then it works fine.

I also name the Scenario 'Scenario: feature setup' and 'Scenario: feature teardown' to make it more obvious when outputting the results to a formatter.

Answer (score -2):

Sure, just tag your feature.

```
After('@mytag') do
  #Do your magic here
end
```

This documentation might help: http://cukes.info/cucumber/api/ruby/latest/Cucumber/RbSupport/RbDsl.html#AfterStep-instance_method

Comment: That will run after a specific tag, per scenario, but not after (and only after) an entire feature (i.e, users.feature).

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question.